# Scala Slick: Cusom mapper type DateTime to datetime

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to store my DateTime objects like DATETIME types into database.So far I couldn't see any example like this and instead I saw a few doing from DateTime to Timestamp or DATE in database.

Someone out there facing the same problem?

My code (not working right now) looks like this:

```
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports.DateTime

object CustomMappers {
   implicit def dateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, DateTime](
        tmap = { dateTimeObject => new DateTime(dateTimeObject.getMillis)},
        tcomap = { dateTimeDb => new DateTime(dateTimeDb) }
  )
}
```

Comment: I can't really find a special mapping in Slick for DATETIME. Did you try with Timestamp class, i.e. converting joda.DateTime to Timestamp? What is in db table then?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't see a DateTime type as you said, which is a bit surprising.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have full control over how this data is stored you can:

1. Specify the database column type when you define the column. Slick makes sensible choices here automatically, but you can use a column option of `O.SqlType` to override it with a (possibly vendor-specific) type.
2. Then provide a customing mapping from your type into a value that makes sense for the database column type you want to use.

The first part is in your table definition:

```
class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[MyClass](tag, "table_name") {
   def when = column[MyDateTime]("my_date", O.SqlType("DATETIME")
   // another example:
   def avatar = column[Option[Array[Byte]]]("avatar", O.SqlType("BINARY(2048)"))
}
```

If you are using Slick to create the schema, the `my_date` column will be given the type `DATETIME`.

For the second part, you provide a mappling like the one in your question. It should be to/from the data type you want to use (DateTime) to a type that makes sense for the `DATETIME` column. For example, the MySQL documentation indicates the format is: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. So what your mapping function should be able to accept and produce `String` types of that format.

## As an alternative...

Since Slick 3.3.0, there's [built-in support for the `java.time`](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/upgrade.html#support-for-java.time-columns) data types. There's not a `DateTime` in Java, but possibly the Java `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` might suit your needs. In this case, there's no need for a mapping or an `O.SqlType`.

Comment: Very helpful @richard. Everything working now as I was planning initially. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

With slick 3.3.0, I found another workaround. (IT should work for other versions also)

`def cusDateTimeCol = column[LocalDateTime]("cusDateTimeCol", O.SqlType("datetime"))(localDateTimeMapper)`

with the following in scope. (use trait and import it in table definition)

```
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  implicit def LocalDateTimeToStr(d: LocalDateTime): String = {
    d.format(formatter)
  }

  implicit def strToLocalDateTime(s: String): LocalDateTime = {
    LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter)
  }

  implicit val localDateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDateTime, String](
    LocalDateTimeToStr(_),
    strToLocalDateTime(_)
  )
```

With this setup, code will read/write datetimes with the format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of usual ISO format.

Comment: nice idea!, it will be useful to have more than one option :)